# Migrating every table to a new linked server has too many prefixes

Tags: sql-server

Unfortunately, I can't backup and restore, since the new database is on an older version of SQL.

When I run the following script, I get this error:

```
    Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    The object name 'eih-dr01.eih.ehs.org.DBA.dbo.fp_monthly' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
```

---

```
    declare @table varchar(255),
    @sql nvarchar(max)

    declare c cursor local for


    select st.name from sys.tables st

    open c

    fetch next from c into @table

    set @sql = 'select * into [eih-dr01.eih.ehs.org].DBA.dbo.' + @table + ' from ' + @table

    print @sql
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from c into @table

    close c
    deallocate c
```

**Question:** Which prefix is superfluous?

**Actual Question** Why aren't my '[',']' charachters showing up in my dynamic sql statement?

Comment: What was the output of the print?

Comment: select * into [eih-dr01.eih.ehs.org].DBA.dbo.fp_monthly from fp_monthly

Comment: but i swear I saw it without the [

Comment: its to do with nvarchar

Comment: You can use a parameter for your server name, since it has dots in it's name. That way yo would avoid this error that you have received.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [SELECT - INTO Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> You cannot create new_table on a remote server using `SELECT INTO`

In other words, the superfluous prefix is the remote server

You could probably achieve your goal by creating empty tables on the remote server and alter your dynamic SQL to

`INSERT INTO server.database.schema.table select from source`

Comment: awwww. Import export wizard it is, then.

Comment: @James Personally I'd just create the table on the server and then change to insert vs insert into. (Right click on table, create as, copy script and run on linked server.) Unsure if you can accomplish this or if there are things in place that make it so you can't do that, but if I can avoid the import gui, I do so whenever possible.

Comment: @Shaulinator i could do it that way, too. I prefer to script. If I wasn't under time constraints, I'd add a create table part to my dynamic sql and do it that way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster yet to run the query on the remote server and SELECT from a source linked server, rather than run the INSERT remotely?

Comment: @JacobH it would, but we are having some trust issues with the hosting company. right now our data flow is, um.... intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly it works the other way around though.

Link old server on the new one and change your select statement to:

```
set @sql = 'select * into DBA.dbo.' + @table + ' from [oldserver].dba.dbo.' + @table'
```

Haven't got anywhere to test it, but I'm almost certain I've done it in the past and it worked just fine.